# IndexError:too many indices for array について

Tags: python, numpy

なぜこのエラーが出るのかがわかりません。
自分の書いたコードはこんな感じです。

```
>>> if __name__=="__main__":
...         data1=np.genfromtxt('./ozon_sheet.csv')
...         x1=data1[:,1]
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
IndexError: too many indices for array
>>>
```

回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3):

csv ファイルは値がコンマで区切られているので、delimiter にコンマを指定すればいいです。

```
data1=np.genfromtxt('./ozon_sheet.csv', delimiter=',')
```

指定しないと空白やタブが区切りに使われるので、csv では思った通りに読み込んでくれません。

ちなみに、csv ファイルの最初の行がヘッダで、カラム名として使いたい場合は names を、単に読み飛ばしたい場合は skip_header を使います。

```
data1=np.genfromtxt('./ozon_sheet.csv', delimiter=',', names=True)
data1=np.genfromtxt('./ozon_sheet.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1)
```